# git merge only one parent not a real merge commit

Tags: git, merge

## Important Info:

**Edit: After third try (I watched MERGE_MODE file in .git directory and it did not disappear) it suddenly worked. I'd really like to know why this process can fail but I think nobody could tell me...**

I have merged multiple branche into one branch.
First merges worked very well but the third did not really "work":

I wanted to merge B into A so I did:

```
git checkout A
git merge B
```

this gave some conflicts which I resolved using gvimdiff:

```
git mergetool -t gvimdiff
git commit
```

But there was no git-prepared standard merge-commit-message but an empty message instead.
That commit has only one parent (commit before merge on branch A).

So what went wrong here any ideas?

Output of `git log --graph --oneline -5 A` (I removed unimportant messages):

```
* 7aaff12 Merge branch B into A.
*   2be0d29 Merge branch C into A
|\
| *   93fe75a Merge conflicts
| |\
| | * ca77a1a <removed commit message>
| | * aeb6f64 <removed commit message>
```

Output of `git log --graph --oneline -5 B`(I removed unimportant messages):

```
* 65a7625 <removed commit message>
* 93bdd81 <removed commit message>
* 4e6c063 <removed commit message>
* ab81b67 <removed commit message>
* 569bdf9 <removed commit message>
```

Output of `git show-branch A B C` (as requested by commentators):

```
! [A] Merges A into C again. Keeps important changes.
 ! [B] <no relevant commit message>
  ! [C] Merge branch 'C_userDB' into C
---
-   [A] Merges A into C again. Keeps important changes.
+   [A^2^2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2^2^] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2^2~2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2^2~3] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2^] Merge branch B into A.
+   [A^2~2^2^2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~2^2^2^] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~2^2^2~2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~2^2^2~3] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~2^2^2~4] Merge Conflicts
+   [A^2~2^2^2~5] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~2^2~2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~3^2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~4] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~3^2^] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~3^2~2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~3^2~3] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~3^2~4] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~6] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~8^2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~8^2^] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~8^2~2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~9] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~10] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~11] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^2~12] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A^] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~3] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~4] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~5] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~6] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~7] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~8^2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~9] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~10] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~11] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~12] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~8^2^] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~8^2~2] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~8^2~3] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~8^2~4] <no relevant commit message>
+   [A~14] <no relevant commit message>
- - [C] Merge branch D into C
+ + [C^2] <no relevant commit message>
+ + [C^] Merge conflicts
+ + [C~2] <no relevant commit message>
+ + [C~3] <no relevant commit message>
+ + [C~4] <no relevant commit message>
 +  [B] <no relevant commit message>
 +  [B^] <no relevant commit message>
 +  [B~2] <no relevant commit message>
 +  [B~3] <no relevant commit message>
 +  [B~4] <no relevant commit message>
 +  [B~5] <no relevant commit message>
 +  [B~6] <no relevant commit message>
 +  [B~7] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~8] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~9] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~10] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~11] <no relevant commit message>
--  [B~12] Merge branch B into A <NOTE: This was to fast-forward this branch after earlier merge>
++  [B~12^2] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~12^2^] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~12^2~2] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~12^2~3] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~12^2~4] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~12^2~5] <no relevant commit message>
--  [B~13] Merge branch 'A_controller' into A
--  [B~13^2] Merge branch 'A_controller_mk' into A_controller
++  [B~13^2^2] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~13^2^] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~13^2~2] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~13^2~3] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~13^2~4] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~13^2~5] <no relevant commit message>
++  [B~14] <no relevant commit message>
--  [B~15] merge conflicts
--- [C~5] Merge branch 'A' into A_logger
```

Comment: You should usually, if not always, get a pre-prepared merge commit message, by default (unless there's a config option that changes that). What's the output of `git log --graph --oneline -5 A` and `git log --graph --oneline -5 B`?

Comment: Notice: I manually wrote the message in commit 7aaff12 because it was empty when i committed.

Comment: The merge of B into A looks like a fast-forward, not a real merge commit. Did you do a fast-forward and not realize it? The graphs imply that you messed up doing a merge somewhere, but I don't have enough information to be sure that that's your case.

Comment: It was defenitley not a fast-forward because I had to resolve some conflicts ;-) Edit: Thats the problem commit 7aaff12 should not look like this. And I don't know why it only has one parent...

Comment: Have you considered just redoing the merge and see what happens?

Comment: Yes I tried to reset to 2be0d29 and merged again but same thing happened

Comment: `git show-branch A B C` please?

Comment: Did you by any chance actually run `git merge --squash B` instead?

Comment: Didn't run `git merge --squash B` not intentionally anyway...

Comment: I have a basically the same problem...And I cannot solve it by just trying again =/

Comment: i think manually recreating the **MERGE_MODE** file by executing `echo "" > /.git/MERGE_MODE` in the root directory of the repository just before running `git commit` solved the problem. Git should know that you are merging then ;)